# Liferay 7 MVC portlet

Tags: liferay-7

I created a MVC portlet in liferay 7 using gradle build type.The build was successful,but portlet is not available under sample category.I checked server console but nothing was there,other than server startup.In between that I am not able to find out the jar location of created portlet.Please help me

```
@Component(
immediate = true,
property = {
    "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
    "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
    "javax.portlet.display-name=Test Portlet",
    "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
    "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
    "javax.portlet.name=" + TestPortletKeys.Test,
    "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
    "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user"
},
service = Portlet.class)

public class TestPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {
    System.out.println("controller is executing");
    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question would be better suited over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You should check jar file under build/lib. If it is present there just copy it to bundle/osgi/modules it will automatically scanned and started.

Comment: Okay can you update your mvc portlet code here, are you sure category is sample??

Comment: Good, run gradlew build in your module folder, if it succeed it will create jar, overright osgi bundle module with this one

Comment: ../../gradlew clean
../../gradlew build

When running this command you should be inside modules/your module

Comment: Can you see gradlew somewhere in your project??

Comment: so why you are not able to run that, check path and permission; There are certain things you could do. 1) Create a simple portlet don't change anything and see if it's working. 2) If you are using 7.0 or 7.1 remove doView, put something in view.jsp compile and then check.

Comment: how to check permission?

Comment: Linux or windows??